# Java - unparseable date, need format to match "GMT-0400"

Tags: java, date, sencha-touch, simpledateformat, web-sql

I have the following Java:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
    "EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss zZ (zzzz)", Locale.ENGLISH);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(2011, Calendar.APRIL, 1);
out.println(formatter.format(cal.getTime()));
out.println();

Date date;
try {
    date = formatter
        .parse("Fri Apr 01 2011 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)");
} catch (ParseException e) {
    out.println("Failed to parse date: " + e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace(out);
}
```

This is in a servlet, and the `Calendar`-constructed date comes out as:

> Fri Apr 01 2011 16:42:24 EDT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

This looks like the same format as the date string I'm trying to parse, except for `EDT-0400` versus the desired `GMT-0400`.  The code fails when trying to parse the date string:

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Fri Apr 01 2011 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)"

How can I parse such a string?  This is coming from a JavaScript date in a Sencha Touch 1.1.1 model, stored in WebSQL local storage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason GMT-0400 isnt' working, and UTC-0400 is working. You can replace GMT with UTC.

Note that this part will be completely ignored - the timezone will be resolved from what's found in the brackets (at least on my machine, JDK 6)

Comment: This seems janky, but doing the following did work:  `date = formatter.parse("Fri Apr 01 2011 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)".replace("GMT-", "UTC-"));`.

Comment: I also tried joda-time, but it can't part the output of its own formatting.

Comment: This answer is sadly wrong. `SimpleDateFormat` will accept UTC-0400 but it will return an incorrect date.

Comment: why would that be? I just tried it - it returns a proper `Date`

Comment: Yes, but not the correct value. It will just parse `UTC` and ignore the rest of the date, so the result will be 4 hours off. This is consistent with the way `SimpleDateFormat` is supposed to operate, i.e. it will end parsing as soon as it found a substring that matches the date pattern.

Comment: Hm, in fact it will ignore that part completely, and will look for the actual time zone in the brackets. I'll include that in the answer

Comment: Ah, I removed the part in brackets and concentrated on the parsing of the `UTC-0400` substring. If we add the bracketed part back, what happens is that it first sets the timezone field to the wrong value, then in the next step overwrites it with the correct one. Brilliant :)

Answer (score 2):

I debugged `SimpleDateFormat` and it seems that it will only parse `GMT-04:00` but not `GMT-0400`.

It will accept `UTC-0400`, however it will throw away the hours/minutes modifier and will incorrectly parse it as `UTC`. (This happens with any other timezone designation, except for `GMT`)

It will also parse `-0400` correctly, so the most robust solution is probably to simply remove `GMT` from your date string.

The upshot of the story is that `SimpleDateFormat` is anything but simple.

Update: Another lesson is that I could've saved a lot of time by passing a `ParsePosition` object to the `parse()` method:

```
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
        "EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss zzzz", Locale.ENGLISH);
    Date date;
    ParsePosition pos = new ParsePosition( 0 );
    date = formatter
        .parse("Fri Apr 01 2011 00:00:00 UTC-0400", pos);
    System.out.println( pos.getIndex() );
```

Will print out `28`, indicating that the parsing ended at character index 28, just after `UTC`.

Comment: Yep, doing `date = formatter.parse("Fri Apr 01 2011 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)".replace("GMT", ""))` with format string `"EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss Z (zzzz)"` worked.