# Unparsable Date exception java

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I am getting date in this format "Sat May 02 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)"

When i parse this using format

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss zZ (zzzz))
```

i get unparsable date exception which obviously means my format is wrong. Can some tell me what could be the right format for this . What to write for "(Pakistan Standard Time)" .

Comment: You can't use `(Pakistan Standard Time)` in your date format. GMT +0500 is sufficient to denote it's a Pakistan Standard Time

Comment: i am getting date in this format , i can't change this

Comment: Than another option is to cut off `(Pakistan Standard Time)` and use rest of the date. it will give you desired outcome

Comment: lol yeah , why the heck did that not come in my mind :p
anyways if i cut that off , is the format ok then?

Comment: Yup it should be perfectly fine

Comment: @SyedMuhammadOan: Change the format to EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z after you removing (Pakistan Standard Time), then it should be ok.

Comment: Related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18493528/java-date-format-gmt-0700-pdt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to parse your date:

```
public class Test {

    static final String sample_date = "Sat May 02 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)".replace("GMT", "")
            .replace(" (Pakistan Standard Time)", "");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
        ParsePosition position = new ParsePosition(0);
        Date d = sdf.parse(sample_date, position);
        System.out.println(d);
        System.out.println(position);
        if (position.getErrorIndex() != -1) {
            System.out.println(sample_date.substring(position.getErrorIndex()));
        }
        System.out.println(sdf.parse(sample_date));
    }
}
```

Reference: [Java - unparseable date, need format to match "GMT-0400"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490373/java-unparseable-date-need-format-to-match-gmt-0400)

Comment: I already got the right answer in the comments but you're answer is the only one i put accept so i accpt this @Sanjeev and unknown had also given the right answer